# Using c# console server with sockets and a html page(client) to get information from it

Tags: c#

> I'm writing a c# changing password page. I haven't done much Socket
>   programming, and I am not sure the best way to go about it.

There's must be console application(the server) and a html page(client)with the following textboxes:

```
Username [_______]
Old password [______]
New password [______]
       [Submit]
```

When the user clicked submit then, a new thread will be created where I'm checking if the information are good and some functions will be executed.

This should accept connections from multiple clients on a defined port.

How can I do this?

What I've done so far is:

```
    public static TcpListener Listener;
    public static int Port = 8080;
static void Main(string[] args)  
   {
        IniFile FPth = new IniFile(@"D:\ServerInfo.ini");
        ServerPort = int.Parse(FPth.IniReadValue("ConnectionINFO", "ServerPort"));
        Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
        Listener.Start();
        Thread NewThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ChangingINFO));
        ChangingINFO();
        Console.WriteLine("Server is ONLINE.");
   }

static ChangingINFO()
{
         while (true)
            {
                Socket Sockt = Listener.AcceptSocket();
                try
                {
                    if (Sockt.Connected)
                    {
                     //Here I should get the information from the client on submit.
                     //But I don't know how
                    }
}
```

But I don't know how to make the html page where I send the info to the server and work with them .

Answer (score 1):

Implementing your own HTTP protocol on top of raw sockets would be a rather large undertaking. You can use Mono XSP to embed a web server that can serve ASP.NET pages into your application, or you can use the HttpListener instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.100).aspx